# Laravel asset minify

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm coming from a django background where we use Django Compressor and the `static` template tag for all of our static file needs.

I'm trying to do something similar in Laravel and i'm finding lots of issue. Much of the older packages no longer work (i'm using 5.x). Is there a place I can find what works in the new version? I tried reading the below links:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationbindshared

http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5

What works in the new version of Laravel? I want to link to static files in my public folder and minify them as well.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir

Comment: Laravel uses `Elixir` which is just a layer on top of `GULP` that prepares tasks in a certain way. If you're familiar with GULP, that'll help.

Comment: Does this mean I have to install `node` on all my servers?

Comment: @KVISH Only on your dev server; after that, just upload the assets.

Comment: You can use easy magnification by using https://packagist.org/packages/vrkansagara/lara-out-press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses Elixir with GULP.

See [Elixir section from Laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/19). If you are not familiar with it, I suggest you [this video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/19).

There's also [this interesting guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/run-gulp-tasks-in-laravel-easily-with-elixir).